# How can I bypass the "Use a local account to log in" page in my ASP.NET account?

Tags: asp.net, single-page-application, visual-studio-2019

After a LONG time away from programming, I am working on a web site. I created a ASP.NET web app (SPA project type). On running it, I get an opening login page with the verbiage: "Use a local account to log in"

How can I bypass this? I have no need for password authentication. I want to go straight to the main page of my site (which I haven't modified yet).

UPDATE

I tried the suggestion below, but the authentication setting (set by default to "Individual User Accounts") is not editable - the "Change" link is greyed out and does nothing when I click it. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Just create a project without authorization...it should be a check box when your creating the project.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani: I noticed no such checkbox; there must be a way, though, to bypass it even after the fact.

Comment: Sorry...there is not a checkbox anymore...see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using VS 2019...**

> Click in Create New Project.
>  Select ASP.NET Web Application(.NET
>   Framework)
>  Click Next
>  Click Create

You will have a dialoge box titled
"Create a new ASP.NET Web Application

**Addendum**
If you select Web Form, MVC or Web API you will have an option to change the
 **Authentication**

> Its here where you can select 
>  No Authentication
>  Individual
>   User Accounts
>  Work of School Accounts
>  Windows
>   Authentication

Comment: The setting is unchangeable for me (greyed out); see my Update for the details.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I think what you need to create is a Web Form and not an application. The web application would be like an API app in which you would need some security.(web application can also be a lot of other things too) but try using Web Forms.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Just curious as to what version of visual studio your using? It seems that the project wizards change a little with every new version.

Comment: VS 2019; just downloaded it a couple of daze ago.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon...see the addendum above....this is what your looking for. You want to select Web form.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Look at the picture you posted above in the original post...It lists: Empty, Web Forms, MVC...pick web forms at that point....sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I got it now - I had to restart my lousy laptop, and my brain first, though.